# Javascript regex fails (loops?)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following text:

```
<meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>test file</title><meta name="GENERATOR" content="LibreOffice 4.1.4.2 (Windows)"><meta name="CREATED" content="0;0"><meta name="CHANGED" content="0;0"><style type="text/css">
    <!--
        .nicEdit-main { margin-left:55px; margin-right:36px; margin-top:18px; margin-bottom:36px }
        P { margin-bottom: 0.21cm; direction: ltr; color: #000000; text-align: left; widows: 2; orphans: 2 }
        P.western { font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; font-size: 12pt; so-language: ru-RU }
        P.cjk { font-family: "Arial", sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; so-language: zh-CN }
        P.ctl { font-family: "Symbol"; font-size: 12pt; so-language: hi-IN }
        TD P { margin-bottom: 0.21cm; direction: ltr; color: #000000; text-align: left; widows: 2; orphans: 2 }
        TD P.western { font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; font-size: 12pt; so-language: ru-RU }
        TD P.cjk { font-family: "Arial", sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; so-language: zh-CN }
        TD P.ctl { font-family: "Symbol"; font-size: 12pt; so-language: hi-IN }
    -->
    </style><div type="HEADER">
    <p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.38cm; text-align: left;" align="LEFT">
    <br><br>
    </p>
</div><p style="margin-top: 0.42cm; margin-bottom: 0.42cm; text-align: center;" class="western" align="CENTER">    <span class="divider">
<b>He</b><i><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><b>-llo</b></span></i><b>,&nbsp;World!!!!!</b></span> </p><p style="margin-top: 0.42cm; margin-bottom: 0.42cm; text-align: center;" class="western" align="CENTER">  <span class="divider"><br></span> <span class="divider"><br></span>  </p><p style="margin-top: 0.56cm; margin-bottom: 0.56cm; text-align: center;" class="western" align="CENTER">  <span class="divider">
<font size="6"><b>h1&nbsp;h1&nbsp;h1</b></font></span>
```

And following regex:

```
/<style type="text\/css">+(.*?\n.*?)+<\/style>/i
```

When i'm testing it on regex tester, regex correctly finds <style></style> section. But when i trying to execute it on live code, it stucks and crashes by timeout on regex.exe()

What i doing wrong?

Comment: What are these `+`s supposed to do in your regex? Please explain

Comment: What do you want to do ? Extract all between `style` tags ? Do you have a live sample ?

Comment: Can you not just use regular element selection methods for this? `document.querySelectorAll('style[type="text/css"]')` will get you all `style` elements with a `type` attribute set to "text/css", for example.

Comment: @Bergi have multiline css block divided with `code`\n`code`, so if `code`<style type="text\/css">(\n.*?)+<\/style>`code` will be w/o +, it would not match entire `code`<style>`code` section

Comment: @NicolasAlbert, have no live example. but yes, extract all style code.

Comment: So what is `(.*?\n.*?)` then supposed to match, a single line of code?

Comment: @Bergi there's mistake. Some trash code. `<style type="text\/css">(\n.*?)+<\/style>` used. Matches prev line-break + one of css rows, multiple times

Comment: @JamesDonnelly thanks. Your solution worked like as i wanted.

Comment: @SergeGlazun: Yes. What you experienced was a case of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Btw, I guess, you want `…>(.*?(?:\n.+?)*)<…` - or even better, just `…>([\S\s]*?)<…`

Comment: @Bergi thanks. Regex is my Achilles heel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `style` element is a regular HTML element and can be pulled using regular JavaScript element-selection methods. For instance, this will get you an array of all `style` elements with a `type` attribute set to "text/css":

```
document.querySelectorAll('style[type="text/css"]');
```

This will give you an array containing every matching element:

```
[
    <style type="text/css">...</style>,
    ...
]
```

To extract the inner content, you can simply use `innerText` on each. For instance, to get the content of the very first matching `style` element, you'd call `innerText` on the `[0]` index:

```
document.querySelectorAll('style[type="text/css"]')[0].innerText;
```